# Modifying packet payload netfilter kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, netfilter

As a learning experience I am trying to create a kernel module that modifies incoming packets from specific IP addresses.  My setup is as follows:

VM1: arpspoofs VM2->VM3 and VM3->VM2, runs kernel module

VM2: nc host

VM3: Connects to VM2 over nc

Right now, I am just trying to change the entire payload to a random character, say 'h', in the future though I will be changing the payload entirely to either a brand new payload or modified payload.  For now I'm just trying to get this to work.

Here is the code I have:

```
unsigned int in_hook(void *priv, struct sk_buff * skb, const struct nf_hook_state *state) {
    struct tcphdr *tcph = tcp_hdr(skb);
    struct iphdr *iph = ip_hdr(skb);
    struct tcphdr *modtcph;
    unsigned char *tail;
    unsigned char *user_data;
    unsigned char *it;
    struct sk_buff * modskb;
    char * tempPay;
    char * payload; //Char array to store original payload before modifications
    int lenOrig;
    int lenNew;
    u16 sport, dport;
    u32 saddr, daddr;
    tempPay = kmalloc(1500, GFP_KERNEL);
    payload = kmalloc(1500, GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!skb)
            return NF_ACCEPT;
    saddr = ntohl(iph->saddr);
    daddr = ntohl(iph->daddr);
    sport = ntohs(tcph->source);
    dport = ntohs(tcph->dest);
    tail = skb_tail_pointer(skb);
    if (saddr == 3232249857) { //IP address of computer SSHing to VM1
            return NF_ACCEPT;
    }
    user_data = (unsigned char *)((unsigned char *)tcph + (tcph->doff * 4));

    if(saddr == 3232249868 || saddr == 3232249869) {  //The IP address of VM2 and VM3
            lenOrig = 0;
            for (it = user_data; it != tail; ++it) {
                    char c = *(char *)it;
                    if (c == '\0') {
                            break;
                    }
                    else {
                            *it = 'h';
                    }
                    payload[lenOrig] = c;
                    lenOrig++;
            }
            ip_send_check(iph);
            payload[lenOrig] = '\0';
            printk("NETFILTER.C: DATA OF ORIGINAL SKB: %s", payload);
    }
    return NF_ACCEPT;
}
```

Now I send through either VM2 or VM3: "hello" or any other string, and I expect on the other VM "hhhhh" but the other VM still sees "hello", what am I doing wrong?  The for loop works fine as payload only has the original packet payload.

My theory is that when conducting the man in the middle attack, the original connect between VM2 and VM3 is never severed, so my module works correctly, but when it sends the new socket buffer to VM3 or VM2, it ignores it as it is not expecting another packet or it sees through the attack and still sees VM1 as VM1 instead of the VM I'm spoofing.

Thanks for all your help!